# Quotes ignored by pdftex

Tags: pdftex, plain-tex, quotation

I'm reading the TeXBook by Donald Knuth, exercise 2.1. I have the following input:

```
Alice said, ‘‘I always use an en-dash instead of a hyphen when specifying page numbers like ‘480--491’ in a bibliog
raphy.’’
\bye
```

Compiling using `pdftex sample.tex` gives the following output. The en-dash works but where are the quotes gone?

[image]

Comment: I don't know how to edit the question but the last double quotes isn't correct it should be ’’ not ”. It doesn't solve my problem anyway.

Comment: I edited your question for you. There is the "edit" button under the tags.

Comment: use `\`\`` and `''` not `‘‘` and `’’` (either works in latex, but not in plain, without further definitions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the curly quotes `‘‘` and `”` use

```
``I always use an en-dash instead of a hyphen when specifying page numbers
like `480--491' in a.''
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it was not obvious at all to me (and it's not the answer given in the book I have, maybe it's an old edition).

Comment: @Alexis816 I did not look in the book, but that's what is in the source code of the book: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/tex/texbook.tex

Comment: @Alexis816 It is the answer in the book, but the book is set in a font in which `\`` and `'` look more curly than on this site.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code of the TeXbook, which is [available on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/texbook), you see

```
\exercise Explain how to type the following sentence to \TeX: Alice said,
``I always use an en-dash instead of a hyphen when specifying page numbers
like `480--491' in a ^{bibliography}.''
\answer |Alice said, ``I always use an en-dash instead of a hyphen when|\break
|specifying page numbers like `480--491' in a bibliography.''| \
(The wrong answer to this question ends with |'480-49l' in a bibliography."|)
```

If you compile with `pdftex` the code

```
Alice said, ``I always use an en-dash instead of a hyphen when specifying
page numbers like `480--491' in a bibliography.''
\bye
```

then copy-paste from the PDF, you get

> Alice said, “I always use an en-dash instead of a hyphen when specifying page numbers like ‘480–491’ in a bibliography.”

because PDF readers are smart enough.

However, you should not use `‘‘` and `’’`, because the characters in the code snippets in the TeXbook actually stand for

```
`` ''
```

Remember that TeX is only using seven bit ASCII characters, whereas `‘` and `’` are not in that range in any encoding.

Answer (score 1):

When TeX and *The TeXbook* were written, computers and software were different in two ways from presently:

1. Each computer / OS had fewer characters (usually at most 256) than the full range of Unicode available today; in particular the curly quotes you entered namely ‘ (U+‎2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) and ’ (‎U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) weren't in their character sets,
2. Instead some systems, including the ones Knuth was familiar with, used the positions currently occupied by ` (U+0060 GRAVE ACCENT) and ' (U+0027 APOSTROPHE) for characters that used to appear visually symmetric and served the same purpose. This history is well explained in the page [ASCII and Unicode quotation marks](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html) by Markus Kuhn (scroll down to "The problem") and also in the [upquote package](http://ctan.org/pkg/upquote).

Correspondingly, the result is that:

1. If you enter non-ASCII characters into TeX, it will misunderstand them and (a serious design flaw IMO) not even complain loudly: you have to look in the `.log` file. To avoid this happening by accident,

   - Put `\tracinglostchars=2` at the top of all files (and use an eTeX-derived engine; the `pdftex` you're using is fine), and/or
   - Always look in the `.log` file whenever TeX says "(see the transcript file for additional information)"
2. When you see what looks like curly quotes in *The TeXbook*, you should understand it (and type it) as ` and ' even though this is clearly wrong according to Unicode and modern fonts -- treat it as a quirk of those fonts.

Bonus: if you just want to use Unicode characters and not bother with the old hacks for achieving things like double quotes and en-dashes using ligatures of ASCII characters, you can use a Unicode engine like XeTeX or LuaTeX. Here's a file that works for the example here; compile with `xetex` or `luatex`:

```
\tracinglostchars=2
% \input luaotfload.sty % Uncomment this line if using LuaTeX
\font\tenrm="[lmroman10-regular]" at 10pt
\rm
Alice said, “I always use an en-dash instead of a hyphen when specifying 
page numbers like ‘480–491’ in a bibliography.”
\bye
```

(Of course then you have to actually remember to use an en dash instead of a hyphen, and also when editing the input file be using a font in which you can easily tell the difference.)